# opencv Mat CV_8UC1 type (uchar) to *unsigned short (*UINT16)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, kinect

This is mainly a C++ variable/pointer handling/casting question.

I am trying to apply one of the openCV library image filters to a depth Image from the Kinect v2 SDK (16bit grayscale, values between 0 and 8092).

I want to do this after getting the depth image but BEFORE using the kinect SDK to do rgb-depth registration and conversion to a point cloud. Therefore I want the final filtered image/array to be of the same type as I received before filtering so I can pass it back to the Kinect SDK.

Initial code:

Get the kinect depth frame as a pointer

```
 UINT nBufferSize = nDepthFrameHeight * nDepthFrameWidth;
 hr = pDepthFrame->CopyFrameDataToArray(nBufferSize, pDepth);
```

create 2 matrices along with the conversion between the 16bit and 8bit(openCV works with 8bit greyscale)

```
Mat depthMat(height, width, CV_16UC1, depth); // from kinect
Mat depthf(height, width, CV_8UC1);

depthMat.convertTo(depthf, CV_8UC1, 255.0/2048.0);
imshow("original-depth", depthf);

const unsigned char noDepth = 0; // change to 255, if values no depth uses max value
Mat temp, temp2;
```

1 step - downsize for performance, use a smaller version of depth image

```
 Mat small_depthf; 
    resize(depthf, small_depthf, Size(), 0.2, 0.2);
```

2 step - inpaint only the masked "unknown" pixels

```
 cv::inpaint(small_depthf, (small_depthf == noDepth), temp, 5.0, INPAINT_TELEA);
```

3 step - upscale to original size and replace inpainted regions in original depth image

```
resize(temp, temp2, depthf.size());
temp2.copyTo(depthf, (depthf == noDepth)); // add to the original signal

imshow("depth-inpaint", depthf); // show results
```

**Problematic Part:**

When I try to reverse the process (even with loss of information for now)

```
cv::Mat newDepth(nDepthFrameHeight, nDepthFrameWidth, CV_16UC1);
depthf.convertTo(newDepth, CV_16UC1,  8092.0 / 255.0);
```

I have found no way to convert these cv::Mat types back to *ushort (*UINT16 in this case).

I have tried things like reinterpret_cast, depthf.data and depthf.ptr() but it keeps showing uchar when hovering over the final data, unless I force it like in the ptr case above, in which case it crashes.
Any ideas?

P.S.: Code works flawlessly if I don't try to filter the depth. Also, crash occurs when the SDK tries to map color and depth and tries to use pDepth in

```
    pCoordinateMapper->MapColorFrameToDepthSpace(nDepthFrameWidth * nDepthFrameHeight, pDepth, nColorFrameWidth * nColorFrameHeight, (DepthSpacePoint*)pDepthSpacePoints);
```

Comment: There are templated overloads of `Mat::ptr`. `newDepth.ptr<unsigned short>()`

Comment: @DanMašek that's what I meant by "unless I force it, in which case it crashes". Exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Please, make a [mcve] that reproduces it. Right now I don't see a reason why it would crash, assuming you're calling it on `newDepth`, rather than `depthf` as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: "but it keeps showing uchar when hovering over the final data" <- do you mean the data member of a mat variable? it is always uchar*.... you can try @DanMašek approach, or just reinterpret cast when you need it outside opencv.... you can always print the type of a mtrix to know if it has changed.... basically opencv saves the bytes of the data array and when you access the data you use the templated function at<>()

Comment: how do you allocate `pDepthSpacePoints`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Here's the update:
I tried with a bunch of breaks/comments and I narrowed it down. 
It's not a problem at the late stages of trying to convert the matrix. 


THE ERROR/CRASH happens when I use either:
-resize/cv::resize 
-inpaint/ cv::inpaint
-even imshow i just realized!

I tried using different types of includes for opencv at the top. To be safe I ended up using include " ", because opencv is already being used without problems in other parts of the project ( I am trying to enrich an existing project, that's why I can't post a MCVE).

Comment: For the sake of completion:

For the sake of completion:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB65637C8C (Kinect20.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000001B6FB38A000.

Comment: I have done some changes in the few months and I assume that if there was a Linker/Library problem it would have appeared in the numerous times that I compiled both in Debug and Release so far.